# 'If' 'else' statement in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, if-statement, sed

I have written code which yield a group of words

```
my $uptime = `command | sed -n "xp" | cut -d" " -fx`;
```

The above command gives me the below word.

```
not running
```

I would like to use this word in an *if* statement like below:

```
if ($uptime = $not){
    $run = `command`;
    $start = `start`;
```

I have declared a variable `$not` and put `"not running"` in it. Though the script is working, it is doing the opposite, when the program is running. The below command gives a different word which (like "ok") is not in the variable `$not`, but the script is restarting the program.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

$not = "not running";
$uptime = `command | sed -n "xp" | cut -d" " -fx`;
if ($uptime = $not){
    # If not running, the program then executes the below, else do nothing
    $run = `cp /home/x`;
    $start = `start`;
}
```

Comment: The `=` operator is an assignment operator. Your conditional is setting `$uptime` to be equal to `$not`.  I'm sure that's not what you want.  In Perl, when you want to compare two strings for equality, you use the `eq` operator: `if( $uptime eq $not ) { ...`.

Comment: What I tried to do is that the below line give a result "not running" > $uptime = `command | sed -n "xp" | cut -d" " -fx`; when not running happen, I wanted to execute what inside in if statement. I thought comparing two string will allow me to execute if statement. Hoever, when I'm using >if( $uptime eq $not ), script is not working.

Answer (score 2):

```
'if ($uptime = $not)' and 'if ($uptime eq $not)'
```

are two different things.`eq` is string comparison operator so it will return 1 when the comparison is equal and `''` when the condition does not satisfy, whereas `if ($uptime = $not)` will return true when `$not` evaluates to true because you are assigning one variable to another using assignment operator `=`. So please change your code.

```
your condition will look like the following .
$uptime=chomp($uptime);
if ($uptime eq $not){
//your code
}
```

Comment: what is your desired output @TahnanALAnas?

Comment: when I get not running from $uptime command, then I want to execute what inside if statement if $uptime give something else than the script will do nothing.

Comment: If providing complete script allowed and give any help, i'll put what I wrote here.

Comment: ya  update the code you are using.but i think the code i mentioned in my answer will do the same you want.

Comment: and check the value of $uptime.make sure it doesnot contain \n or any special character.i guess this may be the reason your condition is failing.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/perl 


use warnings;
use strict;

my $not = "not running";
my $uptime = `qmailctl stat | sed -n "1p" | cut -d" " -f3,4`; (this command give me "not running" if qmailctl not running)
if ($uptime = $not){
my $run = `svscanboot &`;
my $start = `qmailctl start`;

my $email = `echo "qmail-send restarted!" | mail -s "qmail-send <br>restarted on server!" tahnan\@yyy.com`;
}
else{
system "echo 'this is test' | mail -s 'okay!' tahnan.anas\@yyy.com";
}`

Comment: please check what is the value stored in the variable $uptime.or better use chomp() function to remove newline if prsent from the string.

Comment: @TahnanALAnas what is the value in $uptime.?print it just before the if loop.

Comment: the value of $uptime is "not running" or pid depending on the state of qmail process.

Comment: i updated my code.have a look and use chomp function and let me know what is the result.

Comment: @TahnanALAnas did u get ur desired output?

Comment: Still not working, it is not executing what inside if statement. Whenever the server got reboot, qmail service stops and it give below error when i run qmailctl stat. >qmail-send supervise not running. So i tried to write this script to check what is the condition of qmail-send. if qmail-send not running, I need to execute >my $run = svscanboot &; my $start = qmailctl start; However, if I use if ($uptime = $not) than if statement working, as I want to put it on crontab, It will restart qmail-send every time script execute. That why both variable must match.